# StringIndex Error

Tags: java, string

Hi i am very new to java and i cant seem to figure out the issue that i am having here:

```
public static boolean IsPalindrome( String inputString ) {
    String inputString1 = inputString, reverse = "";
    String inputString2 = inputString1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    int length = inputString1.length(); 

    for (int i=length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + inputString2.charAt(i);
    }    
    return inputString.equals(reverse);
}
```

the error that i am getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at MyStringUtils.IsPalindrome(MyStringUtils.java:44)
```

Comment: `inputString2.charAt(i);` -----> `inputString1.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the length of `inputString1` in the loop, but perform actions on `inputString2` which might be shorter. Replace

```
int length = inputString1.length();
```

With

```
int length = inputString2.length();
```

Answer (score 0):

`length` variable contains the length of string `inputString1`, whereas you are looping through string `inputString2` inside the for loop. Since `inputString2` will potentially have less characters than `inputString1` after the replace, it might throw the Exception.

Your  loop should start from `inputString2.length() - 1` instead.

Replace:

```
for (int i=length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

With:

```
for (int i=inputString2.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you want to check if a string is palindrome or not. For this you don't need to generate the reverse and then compare with the orginal . You just simple need to check if it is symetric to the middling character or not. ( first character equal to the last one, second character equal to penultimate character and so on ).

Try this:

```
public static boolean IsPalindrome(String inputString) {
    boolean palindrome = true;

    for (int idx = 0; palindrome && idx < inputString.length() / 2; ++idx) {
        palindrome = inputString.charAt(idx) == inputString.charAt(inputString.length()-1-idx);
    }

    return palindrome;
}
```